# What's the difference between Super Saiyan and Super Saiyan 2?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

It seems Super Saiyan 2 drains my Ki a lot faster than just regular Super Saiyan. Is there a substantial difference between them that makes the much faster drained Ki worth it? My character is a Melee Saiyan, so my character doesn't exactly have much Ki to spare.

Comment: SS consume Ki slower because it's enchancing all your physical attack, SS2 consume Ki faster because it makes all Ki using attack become free

Comment: You can spamming Ultimate Attack using SS2 :D Thats what I do when i meet annoying runner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some slight differences in different battle behaviors.

[This video breaks it all down](https://youtu.be/xmMHjF0-zV8)

But the key points are -

- Combos - SSJ2 is better
- Strike Supers - SSJ2 is better
- Ki Blasts - SSJ2 is better
- Ki Ultimates - SSJ2 is better
- Transformation Duration - SSJ is better

Also  SSJ2 gives you lighting discharge "aura" so there's that.

Answer (score -1):

No, because you have some of it, but not all super saiyans are more durable.

Super Saiyan 2 helps when the battle is long, and gives a power boost to ki blast and ultimate attacks. Super Saiyan 2 is less durable, and has a huge power up; twice the power of Super Saiyan 1.

If the person your fighting is Super Saiyan 2  you can beat them easily, by out lasting your opponent in power transformation. Even if the battle is short, they can still lose by not having enough ki to sustain Super Saiyan 2.

Basically, it some what comes down to Super Saiyan 1. Your base stats effect it alot, too, for example by having a lot of ki. They both mainly help melee attacks, not ki blast attacks.

Comment: If you took the time to format your answer properly, and use this new thing called "punctuation", it might actually be useful. As it stands, I have no clue what you actually said.

Comment: @MrLemon, it lacks punctuation,but it certainly in no way illegible.